# HTML Accessing iframe-"objects" from a clickable list

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, soundcloud

I'm new to this site, but I'll head right into it!

So I'm building a website for my band and we want to have a page where you can access our uploaded music via Soundcloud. I'm already using jquery for some other neat stuff on the site so I think I'll stick to that. Anyway here's a link to the "layout" I'm using. http://gyazo.com/94c87f0b96f58c598b555758e327e1fc So here's what I want:

- Clickable "songtitles"
- When you click on a song the Soundcloud-player changes song.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if I understand correctly what you are willing to do, then you'd need to attach event handlers to your list items with sound titles and then re-set the src of the widget iframe.

I hope this helps.

Comment: (I'm a NOOB, I guess you can tell)

But can you please explain a little bit more about event handlers and how I re-set the src in the iframe? Is there built-in commands in jquery I can use or do I need to "install" another script/css?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really explain all of these. I'd suggest learning through a book like http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html What you need is basically DOM scripting – both event handlers and swapping a source of an element is in that category.

Comment: Thank you! I read a bit on event handlers and swapping a source and this solved my problem! :)